# Understanding the logic behind removing items from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

So, this is my first question here so I apologize if it's not formatted correctly but, basically I am tasked with making a tournament style program for class where 8 teams stored in an arraylist will be eliminated until one is remaining after 3 rounds. Most of the logic seems correct and quiet honestly, I've just hit a bit of a wall on this one.

I've tried different methods of removing the index from the array and have been getting errors each time. After digging, I was able to find some logic that allows me to somewhat run the program without it returning errors. But I believe that I'm just missing something fundamentally. Any insight on what I can do would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuidditchSim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();
        teams.add("The Nomads");
        teams.add("The Cabbages");
        teams.add("The Sparklers");
        teams.add("The Turtles");
        teams.add("The EarthMovers");
        teams.add("The WaterBoys");
        teams.add("The FireMen");
        teams.add("The Noodles");

        int round = 1;
        for (int o = 0; o < 4; o++) {
            System.out.println("Round # " + round);
            System.out.println("=============================================");
            round++;

            for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i = i + 1) {
                playGame(i, i + 1, teams);

            }

            teams.clear();
        }

    }

    public static void playGame(int TeamA, int TeamB, ArrayList<String> teams) {
        int scoreA = 0;
        int scoreB = 0;
        int totalA = 0;
        int totalB = 0;
        boolean gotSnitch = false;
        int quarterNumber = 1;
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(teams.get(TeamA) + " vs " + teams.get(TeamB));

        do {
            if (gotSnitch() == true) {
                int random = rand.nextInt(100);
                if (random % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(teams.get(TeamA) + " are the winner! The snitch was caught.");
                    teams.remove((TeamB));
                    System.out.println("");
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(teams.get(TeamB) + " are the winner! The snitch was caught.");
                    teams.remove((TeamA));
                    System.out.println("");
                    return;
                }
            }
            scoreA = randomScore();
            scoreB = randomScore();
            System.out.println("Qtr " + quarterNumber + ":  " + scoreA + " \t" + scoreB);
            quarterNumber++;
            totalA += scoreA;
            totalB += scoreB;
        } while (totalA == totalB || quarterNumber <= 4);
        {
            if (totalA > totalB) {
                System.out.println(teams.get(TeamA) + " Win " + totalA + " to " + totalB + "! " + teams.get(TeamB) + " eliminated");
                System.out.println("");
                teams.remove((TeamB));
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println(teams.get(TeamB) + " Win " + totalB + " to " + totalA + "! " + teams.get(TeamA) + " eliminated");
                System.out.println("");
                teams.remove((TeamA));
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    public static boolean gotSnitch() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(100);
        if (random > 15) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static int randomScore() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt(4);
        random = random * 10;
        return random;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about actually telling us what the error is?  Maybe even posting your stacktrace?

Comment: One thing to help is to print out the contents of `teams` each time after the call to `playGame`.  Also, why the `teams.clear()` in the loop in `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with your logic but one part. This for loop here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i = i + 1) {
        playGame(i, i + 1, teams);

}
```

The `i` variable in this for will go over the array bounds because on this part of the code

`playGame(i, i + 1, teams);` it tries to access the last index of the array + 1. So your `for` here should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < teams.size() - 1; i = i + 1) {
        playGame(i, i + 1, teams);

}
```

The `teams.size() - 1` will prevent the code to access an index out of the array bounds